# SendGrid does not send emails to Outlook

Tags: outlook, sendgrid

I just started to using `SendGrid` in my `c#` application, and actually I tested this with `Gmail` without any problems, so I tried to send an email also to an `Outlook` email but unfortunately I never reiceved it, I looked also in the spam folder but there is nothing.

I suspect that `Outlook` or `SendGrid` are blocking the `localhost:8081` sender (which actually my application runs).

How can I fix this?